# In Rails 4.2, how do I convert an integer to an enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In Rails 4.2 I can write:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum priority: { normal: 50, low: 0, high: 100 }
end
```

If I have a SQL query which (for obscure reasons) returns the priority as an integer, is there a simple way to convert that integer into its corresponding enumerated value, eg. `:high`?

(Obviously I can look up the key from the value in `Task.priorities`, or define my own reverse index, but presumably this is already implemented *somewhere* in Rails...)

Comment: I'll add that it doesn't take an obscure reason to have Rails give you back the integer. My use case: Service.maximum(:priority), or, more commonly, foo.services.maximum(:priority) -- this return the integer for priority without interpreting through the enum, but it's the latter that I need. Same thing with the :pluck method.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently in ruby 1.9+ I can write:

```
Task.priorities.key(100)
=> "high"
```

No idea if this is efficient, but since the hash table is small...